# VBA to loop through worksheets and clear a dynamic column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to preform the following:
1.) go to the last cell in row 1
2.) offset 1 column to the right
3.) clear that column (column D)
4.) loop through all the worksheets and do the same action

My current code only clears the active worksheet. Thanks for your help!

```
Sub DeleteSumColumn()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Clear
Next
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVHbv.png)

Comment: `ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Clear`

Comment: Use only the following inside the loop: `ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Clear`. There is no need to select anything unless you need the cursor in cell `D1`.

Comment: @VBasic2008: your .End(xlToRight) will fail to get the right-most non-blank cell if there are blank cells in row 1 to the left of the last non-blank cell. The solution from BigBen takes the cursor to the far right column and the .End(xlToLeft) shoots back to the right-most non-blank cell reliably.

Comment: @BigBen I put your code into the for loop and now nothing at all happens. Is something wrong with my for loop structure?

Comment: Maybe add a `Debug.Print ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Column` and inspect the output in the Immediate Window to see what the column in question actually is.